# return time with Linq methods

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

A buddy showed me this Linq statement:

```
records.Where( r => r.Name == "Henry Clay" ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Setting aside the fact that FirstOrDefault() can take a lambda, do all the Henry Clay records get checked for "Henry Clay" before they all go to FirstOrDefault() or does the Where method just return the first one?

In other words could some Henry Clay records never get passed to FirstOrDefault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, all elements are executed lazily. You can see this, when you rewrite the query as follows:

```
records.Where(r =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
    return r.Name == "Henry Clay";
})
.FirstOrDefault();
```

The result will be very different when you force execution, with `ToArray()` for instance:

```
records.Where(r =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.Name);
    return r.Name == "Henry Clay";
})
.ToArray()
.FirstOrDefault();
```

In the last case, `ToArray()` will force the iteration of all elements in the `records` collection, while otherwise, `FirstOrDefault()` will ensure that the collection is stopped iterating after the where predicate returned true for the first time.

Comment: Interesting. What is it about ToArray() that forces the completion of the earlier method?

Comment: @micahhoover `ToArray` doesn't use deferred execution.  It will, when called, immediately process the entire input sequence and generate a result.  All of the `To` methods in LINQ act the same way, as do all of the aggregate operators (`Count`, `Sum`, `Average`, `Aggregate`, etc.).

Comment: That's simple actually. ToArray() creates an array with all the elements, which means it *has* to loop through the complete collection to build the array. An `IEnumerable<T>` (what `Where` returns) on the other hand, is a stream, forward only cursor.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you find an item before the very end, you will not iterate the entire source sequence.  You will stop as soon as the first item is returned.

Here is a helpful analogy.  Imagine a group of people sitting next to each other at a table.  "Mike" is sitting on the far left.  Whenever the person next to him asks him for an item, he will grab a piece of paper out of a stack and give it to the next person.  He'll be the "enumerator" for the underlying data `records`.

Sitting next to him will be "Fred".  Fred, when asked for an item, will ask Mike for an item.  If the item Mike gives him has "Henry Clay" written on it then he'll give it to the next person, if not he'll ask Mike for another item.  This will keep going until Fred finally gets an item that meets his condition, or Mike runs out of items.  He's representing the `Where` enumerator.

To the right of Fred will be "Aaron".  Aaron, when asked for an item, will ask Fred for an item.  When he gets an item from Fred he'll pass it to the next person, and then the next time anyone asks for an item, he'll immediately say "no, I'm already done" without asking Fred for anything else.  He's representing `FirstOrDefault`.

Each person, when asked for an item from the person next to them will, only when asked, get an item from their "source", process it, or do whatever they need to, to generate an item for the next person.  You can imagine, using this example, that once Aaron gets his first item there may very well be sheets of paper left over on the stack.  They will stay there, unprocessed by *anyone*, since Aaron won't ever ask Fred for his second item.

Comment: It's better as a visual, than as text, but that takes a while to put together.